# How to define hour like 24:00 and don't change to 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to input a time with inputmask (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) but did not succeed.

In this link: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/1786 he say that it take define inputformat like HHH but still yet i don't got it.

Datetime: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/4.x/README_date.md

(Don't work) Code example with HHH: https://jsfiddle.net/vy1jwuwn/21/

```
Inputmask("datetime", {
    inputFormat: "HHH:MM",
    max: 24
}).mask("input");
```

(Work until 23:59) Code example with HH: https://jsfiddle.net/n3sgqeLb/1/

```
Inputmask("datetime", {
    inputFormat: "HH:MM",
    max: 24
}).mask("input");
```

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? The HHH feature is in 4.x.

Comment: This is a classic problem. In most systems there simply is no such thing as 24:00 time - it is 00:00 of the next day. That is why insurance policies will usually say 11:59pm or 12:01am - to avoid such confusion. And yet, I have one system I work with that sends 15-minute data and sends the last chunk of each day as 24:00. So a "proper" system will not support it, which is why you are having problems making it work. I normally set up input fields using 11:59pm (or 23:59) as the end point, even though all the others are :00 (or :00, :15, :30, :45 for 15-minute data), etc.

Comment: If you use just the hour part then its working correct: https://jsfiddle.net/vy1jwuwn/50/ like RobinHerbots commented in your linked issue. I think there is an issue, using hour with minutes.